# How to promote DOM range after inserting a Node?

Tags: javascript, dom

I insert a node and when insert another it substitutes the previously inserted one.

I guess I need to put the range after the firstly inserted node, but how?

I define a function:

```
function EmoticonsMenu(jquery_element){
  var e = jquery_element;
  var top  = e.offset().top;
  var left = e.offset().left;
  var onIconClick_callback;

  this.onIconClick = function(eventObject){
    var html = $(eventObject.target).parent().html().replace(/\n\s+|\s+\n/g, '');
    onIconClick_callback(html);
    };

  e.blur(function(){
    e.css({visibility:'hidden'});
    e.hide();
    });

  this.attach_to = function(element, callback){
    onIconClick_callback = callback;
    var newTop  = element.offset().top  - top  - 10 - e.height();
    var newLeft = element.offset().left - left + 10;
    e.css({top:newTop, left:newLeft});
    e.css({visibility:'visible'});
    e.focus();
    };
};
```

and there is a place where I bind Emoticon to my nicEditor custom button

```
  nicEditorExampleButton = nicEditorButton.extend({   
    mouseClick : function(eventObject) {
    // get nicEdit selected instance - se
    var se = this.ne.selectedInstance;

    var paste_icon_html = function(html){
      // create a DOM node from the string
      //var html = '<img src="/assets/emoticons/ac.gif">admin is here!</img>';
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.innerHTML = html;
      var node = div.childNodes[0];

      // get selection if any, insert html as a Node
      var range = se.getRng();
      range.deleteContents();
      range.insertNode(node.cloneNode(true));
      //range.setStart(node,0);
      //range.setEnd(node,0);
      };

    emoticonsMenu.attach_to($(this.button), paste_icon_html);
    }
  });
  nicEditors.registerPlugin(nicPlugin,nicExampleOptions);
```

Comment: What does `se.getRng()` do?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to substitute anything, remove the call to [`deleteContents`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/range.deleteContents).

Also you might have the problem that while calling this snippet repeatedly you always refer to the same `nodes[0]`, and it can only exist once - to insert it multiple times, you'd need to [clone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.cloneNode) it:

```
range.insertNode(nodes[0].cloneNode(true));
```

Comment: but I need to substitute any selection, and get the selection with range

Comment: I clone the node `range.insertNode(nodes[0].cloneNode(true));` but it still is being overwritten.

Comment: overwritten by what? Please post your whole script, or link a short demo (e.g. at http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: It's overwritten by the second choosen icon. I've posted the whole script. Maybe I have to use range.setStart, setEnd methods?

Comment: Hm, no, you should not need to use `clone` here as the `<img>` node is unique here. What do you mean by "second choosen", could you post how you call the function?

Comment: Uh, that's much but still incomplete code... Could you make a working demo from it that shows the error?

Comment: Sorry, I doubt I can prepare working demo, because there are more code which initialize nicEditor and many much more html source that is generated by nicEdit with its nested divs and tricky attributes. I updated the secons snippet as I cut the end posting it before. Thank you for your attention!!! Now looking at setStartAfter, setEndAfter, ... looking promising.

Comment: Thanks. I can't see anything obvious, but maybe your problem is that the `se` variable does not update?

Answer (score 0):

Here is code change required. Instead of:

```
  range.insertNode(node.cloneNode(true));
  //range.setStart(node,0);
  //range.setEnd(node,0);
  };
```

should be

```
  range.insertNode(node);
  range.setEndAfter(node);    //++
  range.setStartAfter(node);  //++
  };
```